# Spring-Retry with Circuit breaker

Tags: spring, spring-retry, circuit-breaker

I am trying to leverage both the retry and circuit breaker mechanism of spring-retry. 
I tried to use both annotations(@Retryable and @CircuitBreaker) in a particular function(like below), but Circuit Breaker was not working.

```
@Service
public class CommandAndRetry {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleRetryService.class);

    @CircuitBreaker(maxAttempts = 1, openTimeout = 10000)
    @Retryable(
            value = {TypeOneException.class},
            maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(2000))
    public void retryWhenException() throws TypeOneException {
        LOGGER.info("Retrying");
        throw new TypeOneException();
    }

    @Recover
    public void recover(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.info("SampleRetryService.recover");
        throw t;
    }
}
```

Then I tried dividing the functionality into two different functions, both having @Retryable and @CircuitBreaker respectively. In this case, retry mechanism was not working. Please find below code snippet.

PS: exec method(Circuit Breaker method) is invoked from a controller.

```
@Service
public class CommandAndRetry {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleRetryService.class);


    @CircuitBreaker(maxAttempts = 1, openTimeout = 10000)
    public void exec() throws TypeOneException {
        retryWhenException();
    }

    @Retryable(
            value = {TypeOneException.class},
            maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(2000))
    public void retryWhenException() throws TypeOneException {
        LOGGER.info("Retrying");
        throw new TypeOneException();
    }

    @Recover
    public void recover(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.info("SampleRetryService.recover");
        throw t;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell why it's behaving like this.

Also please advise if there exists a better way to implement both retry and circuit-breaker. 
PS: I neither want to use resilience4j nor retryTemplate.

Comment: I guess it is because `CircuitBreaker` is a `Retryable` by itself.

Comment: Yes, but is there any way to configure it? like setting Backoff

Comment: The first won't work because, as @yegodm says, it is, itself `@Retryable` - see my answer for how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want retry within circuit breaker, they must be in different beans. If you call one `@Retryable` directly from another, in the same bean, you will bypass the interceptor.

This works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRetry
public class So52193237Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So52193237Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            try {
                foo.exec();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    foo.exec();
                }
                catch (Exception ee) {
                    Thread.sleep(11000);
                    try {
                        foo.exec();
                    }
                    catch (Exception eee) {

                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Component
    public static class Foo {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);

        private final Bar bar;

        public Foo(Bar bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @CircuitBreaker(maxAttempts = 1, openTimeout = 10000, resetTimeout=10000)
        public void exec() throws TypeOneException {
            LOGGER.info("Foo.circuit");
            this.bar.retryWhenException();
        }

        @Recover
        public void recover(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
            LOGGER.info("Foo.recover");
            throw t;
        }

    }

    @Component
    public static class Bar {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Bar.class);

        @Retryable(value = { TypeOneException.class }, maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(2000))
        public void retryWhenException() throws TypeOneException {
            LOGGER.info("Retrying");
            throw new TypeOneException();
        }

        @Recover
        public void recover(Throwable t) throws Throwable {
            LOGGER.info("Bar.recover");
            throw t;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also I was trying to configure maxAttempts of circuit breaker. Seems like maxAttempts of circuit breaker is constant and we can't configure from properties file. Is there any workaround  for this ?

Comment: No; it's not; unlike `@Retryable`, it doesn't have `...Expression`-flavored attributes. Perhaps open a new feature request issue [against the project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues). I suppose you can double wrap it as as workaround - retryable calls a circuit breaker (with =1) which calls a retryable.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But that doesn't give me opentimeout and resetTimeout configurationa

Comment: Right; they will need code changes in the framework to be configurable.

Comment: There is already an [open issue here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/123). I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Also, can we use hystrix circuit breaker in place of spring-rety circuit breaker ? Need configurable circuit breaker settings

Comment: I have a similar pattern but it retry for 6 times in place of 3

Comment: Don't comment on 3 year old answers; ask a new question showing your code and configuration.

Comment: @GaryRussell Sorry, Please have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69742521/spring-retry-sending-duplicate-request