# Spring retry sending duplicate request

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry, circuit-breaker

I can see in the logs that Spring retry is sending 2 requests to the remote server and both requests return successful responses.

I am not able to get the reason behind the same.

**Code:**

```
Class StatusClient{

       @CircuitBreaker(maxAttemptsExpression = "#{${remote.broadridge.circuitBreaker.maxAttempts}}",
                openTimeoutExpression = "#{${remote.broadridge.circuitBreaker.openTimeout}}", resetTimeoutExpression = "#{${remote.broadridge.circuitBreaker.resetTimeout}}")
        public Optional<JobStatusResponseDTO> getStatus(String account, String jobNumber) {
    
        client.post()
                    .uri(PATH)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(request))
                    .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                        if (response.statusCode() == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) {
                            return Mono.empty();
                        } else if (isClientOrServerError(response)) {
                            return Mono.error(new RemoteClientException(String.format("status is not received: %s", response.statusCode())));
                        }
    
                        stopWatch.stop();
                        log.info("time taken by the getStatus=[{}] for {}", (stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis()), request);
                        return response.bodyToMono(JobStatusResponseDTO.class);
                    })
                    .block();
    
            return Optional.ofNullable(block);}
}
    
    Class status{
    
     @Retryable(maxAttemptsExpression = "#{${remote.retry.maxAttempts}}", backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{${remote.retry.delay}}"))
        public Optional<JobStatusResponseDTO> getStatus(String jobNumber, String accountNumber) {
            return statusClient.getStatus(accountNumber, jobNumber);
        }
    }
```

Config in application.yml

```
circuitBreaker:
      maxAttempts: 3  # defalut 3
      openTimeout: 5000 # defalut 5000
      resetTimeout: 20000   # defalut 20000
    retry:
      maxAttempts: 3 # defalut 3
      delay: 1000 # defalut 1000
```

Logs:

```
792 <14>1 2021-10-26T16:26:32.978917+00:00 -  2021-10-26 16:26:32.978 INFO [batch,ec40b8fe1f6a4cfb,06052e092b3f8e66] : time taken by the getStatus=[582] for JobStatusRequestDTO(account=12
        456, jobNumber=S123456)
        
        792 <14>1 2021-10-26T16:26:18.263121+00:00 2021-10-26 16:26:18.262 INFO [batch,ec40b8fe1f6a4cfb,21202725a0002bde] : time taken by the getStatus=[592] for JobStatusRequestDTO(account=12
        456, jobNumber=S123456)
```

Both the request are a few seconds apart.

**Edit 1:**
changed circuit breaker to the max attempt to 1. Now it is retrying 3 times. There is still an issue. It seems it is calling the remote server only once and not calling after.
The remote call is wrapped in a circuit breaker.

**1st Attempt log:**

```
status is not received: 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
```

**2nd Attempt log:**

```
org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Retry exhausted after last attempt with no recovery path;
```

**3rd Attempt log:**

```
org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Retry exhausted after last attempt with no recovery path;

circuitBreaker:
      maxAttempts: 1
      openTimeout: 5000 # defalut 5000
      resetTimeout: 20000   # defalut 20000
    retry:
      maxAttempts: 3 # defalut 3
      delay: 1000 # defalut 1000
```

Comment: I just tested it and it works as expected for me; I suggest you print a stack trace in `getStatus` to see where it is being called from each time.

Comment: @GaryRussell yes, it s retrying only 3 times bt there is an issue. please see edit 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have placed the default retry.maxAttempts to 3 with a delay of 1000ms. Spring will auto-retry if there is no response within the mentioned delay time. So, replace the retry.maxAttemps to 2 then it won't give multiple responses.

you can simply paste below lines in application.properties.

```
retry.maxAttempts=2
retry.maxDelay=100
```

Also, I suggest you go through [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry).